# Extensions not loading in Chrome driver Profiles Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am wanting to use Profiles in Selenium Chrome.
I have tried:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Bain3\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

I do not believe the profile is being loaded correctly as the extensions are not being loaded with it and instead gives me normal chrome with chrome automation extension.  I have done this in geckodriver with no issues.

My next question is, as I want to use profiles in Selenium chromedriver.  How do I remove the profiles icon and images from Chrome as I often use Chrome by default.  It seems pointless to have these icons when I already have names for the profiles in the shortcuts.
I tried:

```
start "" "c:\program files (x86)\google\chrome\application\chrome.exe" --new-window --disable-new-avatar-menu
```

as well as navigating through `chrome://flags/` 
Any ideas on why extensions are not being loaded with profiles and if the profile button in chrome can be disabled as well as the icons?

Here's an image of the icons and profiles icon that I could not get to be disabled.  https://ibb.co/hS4N45 .

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue then i used the extension crx file to add it on launch by using :

```
options.add_extension("idmgcext.crx")
```

the crx file is in the same folder as the script or provide full path if in another folder you can get chrome extension crx file using this site: https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/